# Unexpected results for Plotting a Histogram of a GroupBy DataFrame in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

`docs_df2.sample(10)`
[image]

And the dtypes are:

```
filetype     object
hash         object
num_users     int64
num_tags      int64
dtype: object
```

Now I want to see what the distribution of `num_tags` look like, so I plot the count() of the dataframe grouped by `num_tags` (`hash` is unique):

[image]

So far so good, but I want a histogram now, so that I can see clearly the power law nature of my data, I get results by I think they're sort of *plotted the wrong way around*:

`docs_df.groupby('num_tags')['hash'].count().plot(kind='hist')`:

[image]

This is not what I want, though.

What I would like is to have the different "types" of `num_tags` (all 31 of them) in the **x-axis** ordered by their frequency, and the actual frequency in the **y-axis**.

Something like this:

[image]

Comment: could you not post your data in picture ?

Comment: Your making a histogram of counted numbers, that's not going to give you what you want, instead maybe just, `docs_df.num_tags.plot(kind='hist')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are trying to make is not actually a histogram. A histogram would be used to display the frequency (count) of some measure while fitting a range of measures into a specified number of bins. You have already counted the data. What you want is a sorted bar graph. As an example, since I can't use your data...

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,10,(1000,2)),columns=['num_users','num_tags'])
df.groupby('num_tags').count()['num_users'].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image: Unsorted Bar Plot]

Now we just need to sort the bars

```
df.groupby('num_tags').count()['num_users'].sort_values(ascending=False).plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]